# How to create download button using href - (Flask)?

Tags: python, flask

In my project, I can save files into the directory and save its path to the database. Here is the code

```
def save_file(form_file):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_file.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/files', picture_fn)
    form_file.save(picture_path)
    return picture_fn

@app.route('/ticket/<int:ticket_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def ticket(ticket_id):
    ticket = Tickets.query.get_or_404(ticket_id)
    com = Comment.query.filter_by(ticket_id=ticket.id).first()
    form = CommentForm()
    attachform = AttachForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and form.body.data:
        comment = Comment(body=form.body.data,ticket_id=ticket_id,author = current_user.username)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your comment has been published.')
        return redirect(url_for('ticket', ticket_id=ticket_id))
    if attachform.validate_on_submit():
        if attachform.file.data:
            picture_file = save_file(attachform.file.data)
            attachment = Attachment(file=picture_file,ticket_id=ticket_id)
            db.session.add(attachment)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your file has been published.')
        return redirect(url_for('ticket', ticket_id=ticket_id))
    file = url_for('static', filename='files/' + str(ticket.attach))
    return render_template('ticket.html', title=ticket.title,file=file ,ticket=ticket,form=form,comment=com,attachform=attachform)
```

Now how do i make so that when i click on the name of the file it would get downloaded?
Here is my html file

```
{% for fil in ticket.attach %}
        <ul class="list-group">
            <a href="{{ file }}" download class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> {{ fil }}</a>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

but it downloads some weird html file not the actual file

Comment: Typo in template code `for fil in ticket.attach` ... `{{file}}`?

Comment: I did change this typo but still doesn't work

Comment: I'm guessing `str(ticket.attach)` in that second last line isn't returning what you think it is.  I'd either add a `print (str(ticket.attach))` line in there to debug, or view the source of the rendered page to ensure the correct link is being rendered in that `href` attribute.  Either way: There's probably a good case for creating a separate route (with an auth decorator) which returns the file (using `send_file`), which has been stored in a separate 'uploads' directory, rather than serving it from 'static/'.  Unless of course you want user uploads to be public.

Comment: @v25 Thank you, I was able to manage it to work. I will attach the correct answer down below. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @v25 suggested I've created a separate `download` function with `send_from_directory` flask extension.

```
 @app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def download(filename):
        uploads = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
        return send_from_directory(directory=uploads,filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
```

html file

```
{% for file in ticket.attach %}
        <ul class="list-group">
            <a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=file) }}" download class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> {{ file }}</a>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Glad you got this working. Nice one on posting the follow-up also :)